# jQuery .addclass on a checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms, class, checkbox, addclass

I'm trying to add a class to multiple elements in a form. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"],select,input[type="submit"],input[type="checkbox"]').addClass("idleField");
```

It does work for all except for the checkbox. Any idea why?

Note: I have also tried doing it with these syntax:

:checkbox

#myForm :checkbox

Thank you!

Comment: More info needed. What browser is this happening on ? Does it happen all the time ? On load ? Can you group your checkboxes to a family and apply this class to the family and see ?

Comment: [Let me put that in a jsfiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/F9wyh/) I am not seeing the problem.

Comment: This is happening on Chrome and Firefox, but works on IE. It is executed when the DOM is fully loaded. There is only one checkbox I need this to be applied on, and I tried giving the class in the CSS and it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide your CSS? Works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly fine for me. Maybe you're styling your checkbox incorrectly?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjxUu/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**CSS**

```
.idleField {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"],select,input[type="submit"],input[type="checkbox"]').addClass("idleField").addClass("idleField");
});
```

### Update

It's working in your jsFiddle, your styles can't applying to the checkbox though. Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are determined by your operating system and can't be styled in the same manner as text boxes for example. Normally styling checkboxes or radio buttons involves hiding the original input and then creating a new div (or a label) and styling that maybe with a pseudo-element.

[image]

Comment: Here is a fiddle that could be useful:
http://jsfiddle.net/F9wyh/1/

As you see the checkbox has no styling applied, that's what it does on my code

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/otoras/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(':text, :password, :submit, select, :checkbox').addClass("idleField");
```